# App-Controlled Cat® D11 Bulldozer

Tags: technic, remote-control, control-plus

I'm having a problem with the App-Controlled Cat® D11 Bulldozer (42131).

The option Module 2 test has disappeared from the app. How do I get it back?

Comment: Welcome to Bricks.SE.  Have you tried rebooting or updating?

Comment: uninstalled app and reinstalled it. No luck. there doesn't appear to be a manual way to upgrade. I've built up to end of module 4. Functions all seem to work. I've one track unit built and installed. Both turn same way know no. Just thinking that at the test function I may have  tried turning the d11